# p-adic period map in Lawrence and Venkatesh

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-hodge-theory

In Lawrence and Venkatesh's paper on the Mordell conjecture, they prove that there are finitely many $K$-rational points on a hyperbolic curve $X$, where $K$ is a number field, by showing that there exists an analytic function on the $p$-adic curve $X(K_v)$ vanishing on $X(K)$, where $v$ is some arbitrary place above $p$, a prime of good reduction for the curve $X$.

LV prove the existence of such a $p$-adic analytic function by showing that there is some analytic map $\Phi : X(K_v)\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}$, called the $p$-adic period map, which has a certain flag variety $\mathcal{F}$ as its target, with the property that:

- The image of $\Phi$ in $\mathcal{F}$ has Zariski closure of dimension greater than that of the Zariski closure of the image of $\Phi|_{X(K)}$.

They deduce that there has to exist a non-zero $p$-adic analytic function on $X(K_v)$ that vanishes on $X(K)$. My question is: why is this a consequence of the previous statement, i.e. why does the inequality of dimensions imply the existence of such a function?

If this is somehow helpful, this is explicitly stated in Lemma 3.3 of their paper.

Comment: Dear @kindasorta, Please note that the $p$-adic period map is defined on a residue disk, but in general not on the whole $X(K_v)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V_K,V_{K_v}$ be the Zariski closures of images of $\Phi$ and $\Phi|_{X(K)}$, respectively. Since $V_{K_v}$ has higher dimension than $V_K$, it is a proper subvariety, which means there must be some nonzero regular function $f$ on $V_{K_v}$ which vanishes on $V_K$. Since $X(K_v)$ is Zariski dense in $V_{K_v}$ (by definition), $f$ must be nonzero on some element of $\Phi(X(K_v))$. That is to say, $f\circ\Phi$ is nonzero on $X(K_v)$, but it will vanish on $X(K)$. Hence $f\circ\Phi$ is the desired function.

Edit: the above doesn't quite work, since $V_{X(K)}$ need not be affine. But also the statement as written in the post is different from the one cited in Lemma 3.3 (indeed the statement in the OP is wrong - as $X(K_v)$ is compact, it admits no nonconstant analytic functions).

The statement in the lemma instead amounts to a local version of this statement: let $\Omega$ be the $v$-adic unit disk in $X(K_v)$ and let $S\subseteq\Omega$ be a subset such that $\Phi(S)$ is contained in a proper subvariety of the Zariski closure of $\Phi(X(K_v))$ (for instance, in the setting of the question, $S=\Omega\cap X(K)$). Then there is a nonzero analytic function on $\Omega$ which vanishes on $S$.

Using the argument I gave above, we can prove this locally: by taking an affine subset $U$ of $V_{K_v}$, we *can* find a regular function which vanishes on its intersection with $\Phi(S)$. It implies that $\Phi^{-1}(U)\cap S$ is contained in a vanishing locus of an analytic function on $\Phi^{-1}(U)$. This should be sufficient for finiteness as $S$ is covered by finitely many such subsets.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a proper subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$, but there is no non-zero regular algebraic or analytic function $f$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ that vanishes on your favorite embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Could you elaborate on why such $f$ exists? In which category does it live?

Comment: @kindasorta Oops, you are right, my argument would have worked if we were working with affine varieties, but that is not the case here. By working locally on $V$'s I believe we can deduce that $X(K)$ is locally contained in a vanishing locus of such an analytic function. I have looked at the paper and it seems that Lemma 3.3 isn't claiming anything more - they only make a claim about subsets of the disk $\Omega_v$, not the entire projective variety

Comment: The disk $\Omega$ is a residue disk on the $p$-adic curve $X(K_v)$. My worry is that $V_K$ and $V_{K_v}$ could be projective, in which case it is unclear to me how one comes up with such a function on $V_{K_v}$. If such a function exists then it is clear that it may be pulled back to a nonzero function on $X(K_v)$.

Comment: I think that the property you were referring to was properness and not compactness as in the complex analytic category. However, being hyperbolic does not imply being proper, so for example, in the case of the punctured line, there is no obstruction as the one you mentioned for the existence of a global analytic function.

Comment: @kindasorta In this case, unless $X(K_v)$ is empty, then properness should be equivalent to compactness. And while you are right that general hyperbolic curves are not always proper, it ought to be an assumption in your problem - non-proper hyperbolic curves can have infinitely many rational points over $K$, it is integral points over $O_K$ which they have only finitely many of. And anyway, considering $X$ proper is enough to see the statement is not true in general.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I guess there is no harm done thinking of the problem one residue disk at a time. Thanks for writing a detailed reply. BTW, while I understand YOUR argument, are you sure that this is precisely what they do in THEIR paper?

Comment: @kindasorta I am not! I wanted to add some remarks about that in the answer, but I was not confident in their validity and they didn't seem necessary. My idea was that perhaps after showing that this set is locally contained in a vanishing locus, perhaps one can argue cohomologically (using essentially resolutions of Cousin's problems over $K_v$) that one can glue the functions defining respective loci into a single one. However it is not at all obvious that the functions I produce can be chosen "compatibly" (it is true a posteriori by finiteness, but that doesn't seem clear from the argument)